# Cannot display the π value for i= 100, 500, 1000, 10000

Tags: python

```
import math
total = 0

for q in [100, 500, 1000, 10000]:
    for k in range(1, q):
        pi = (-1 ** (k + 1)) / (2 * k + 1)
        total = total + pi
        total = -total

approximate_pi = 4 * total
real_pi = math.pi

print("Pi approximate value is:", approximate_pi, "Pi is", real_pi)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of "what am i doing wrong", can you state what goes wrong and what result you want?

Comment: Are you asking for lengths of pi, the 100oth digit of pi, or what?

Comment: @Marios - That's okay, as long as OP clearly describes the problem and has attempted a solution.

Comment: the question is Write a program that displays the π value for i = 100, 500, 1000 and 10000. Your program should also display the
difference between the approximate π value that you calculated with the series formula and the π value using math
library (use math.pi).

Comment: using this eq: pi = 4(1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 + ((-1)^i+1)/2i - 1)

Comment: It seems like you are just copying a homework assignment. But what the heck is a "pi value for i"? As mentioned by @Marios, if all you are doing is pasting a homework assignment here, you may not have much luck.

Comment: Oh, okay, just saw the equation.

Comment: I'm sorry I have been stuck on this question for 6 hours its okay if you can't help I understand and to answer your question i is for the equation pi = 4(1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 + ((-1)^i+1)/2i - 1 . I need to use 'for i [100, 500, 1000, 10000]'

Comment: I am not copying I just need to know what did I do wrong to fix my mistakes my apologize

Comment: I can't figure out how the iteration is envolved... sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

This approximation is called the [Gregory–Leibniz series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80). You have a few issues with your code. First of all, it looks like you are trying to make four approximations, not one. Each approximation is using more and more iterations, so it should get more precise. The other main issue is `(-1 ** (k + 1))` does not work quite like you hope. In python `-1 ** 0 == -1` while `(-1) ** 0 == 1`. This should work a bit better:

```
import math

for q in [10, 500, 1000, 10000]:
    total = 0
    for k in range(q):
        total += ((-1) ** k) / (2 * k + 1)
    print(f'with {q} iterations: {total * 4}')

real_pi = math.pi

print("Pi is", real_pi)
```

Results:

```
with 10 iterations:  3.0418396189294032
with 500 iterations:  3.139592655589785
with 1000 iterations:  3.140592653839794
with 10000 iterations:  3.1414926535900345
Pi is 3.141592653589793
```

If you add larger values to your list, you should get increasingly better approximations.

Comment: Thank you soo much I really appreciate it, I can see my silly mistakes.